# Google+like cell backgrounds on android

Tags: android, listview, drawable

I'm trying to duplicate the white box with a slight drop shadow effect that google+ has in their app.

I've done a significant amount of playing around with methods of accomplishing this. I've found that 9-patch images cause a significant lag on older devices. I've since switched to trying to replicate using a  however, I can't seem to get the drop shadow quite right.

I've tried many methods including adding gradients to the shape, converting the drawable to a bitmap applying a shadow to the bit map then casing back to a drawable and setting it as the background image of my view. However, none of which seem to give me the effect that I want.

Does anyone know a efficient way to draw these boxes for each view in a list view.

(just as a side note I don't care about the 2 columns I just want the view background that they have without having to use a 9patch.

[image]

Comment: How are you creating this shadow effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Google+ apk they used 9-patch images for all of the shadows. I think the 9-patch images are exactly what you want. You may want to pull down the APK and look at their resource folder and the size of their 9-patch images. Maybe yours are poorly optimized for smaller screen devices?

Comment: How exactly does one optimize 9-patch images? Also should I apply the 9patch directly to the view in the XML or via code?

Comment: That will mean low DPI images in the relevant drawable folders. I am going to delete my answer since `windowContentOverlay` is only affecting views in the title/statusbar.  You may want to look into the cache settings for backgrounds on `ListView` to speed up rendering.  Also, enabling debugging slows `ListView`s massively on my ADP2.

Comment: I would just apply the 9-patch in the XML but I can't imagine it would make a difference compared to code. As for optimizing, as @techiServices stated, re-size them per DPI folder. If you have a rooted device, or Google a bit, you can get a copy of the APK and pull out the shadows they use from their res/drawable folders.

Comment: I tried using the 9-patch images from their apk and they dont seem to be right. Looks like wrapping a layout with a background of #FFFFFF in a layout with a 1dp padding on the right and bottom with a background of about #AAAAAA or #BBBBBB gives the right look. Might need to play with the colors a bit to get it exactly right, this was just quickly eyeballing it.